# Bing map method to convert UK postcodes to Latitudes and Longitudes using bing maps version 7.0?

Tags: jquery, bing-maps

Is there any method to convert UK postcodes to Latitudes and Longitudes using Bing Maps version 7.0? I have an array which has postcodes but unable to find the latitudes and longitudes.

Answer (score 1):

With Bing Maps AJAX V7, you have the possibility to use the Search module to performs a geocoding operation based on the postcode.

See the MSDN for SearchManager - geocode method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868062.aspx

And here a live example: 
http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#SearchModule2

You can use the REST service directly with URI like: 
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/UK/postalCode?includeNeighborhood=includeNeighborhood&maxResults=maxResults&culture=en-GB&key=BingMapsKey